# How can I write this query using PIVOT without getting "syntax error"

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT id, revenue, month FROM Department)
pivot 
(MAX (revenue) 
FOR month IN  (Jan Jan_Revenue, Feb Feb_Revenue,
              Mar Mar_Revenue, Apr Apr_Revenue,
              May May_Revenue, Jun Jun_Revenue,
              Jul Jul_Revenue, Aug Aug_Revenue,
              Sep Sep_Revenue, Oct Oct_Revenue, 
              Nov Nov_Revenue, 'Dec' Dec_Revenue))
```

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
> corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
> near '(revenue) FOR month IN  (Jan Jan_Revenue, Feb Feb_Revenue, Mar
> Mar' at line 4

Comment: I removed the incorrect SQL Server tag; you should tag *only* the database you are using.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please edit your question to include the CREATE TABLE statement for Department. Also include some sample data and what you would like to see as output.

Comment: `pivot` is not supported by MySql.

Comment: What is the data type of your fields? Do you have sample data? Why do you want to get the *max* revenue per month? Does it not make more sense to get the *sum* of revenue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT id,
       max(case when month = 'Jan' then revenue end) as jan_revenue,
       max(case when month = 'Feb' then revenue end) as feb_revenue,
       . . . 
FROM Department d
GROUP BY id;
```